# What does (deleted) mean in android app crash callstack?

Tags: android, crash, callstack

I got a crash callstack like this:

```java
    #00 pc 000000000208f46c  /data/data/com.xxx/files/cips/common/mtplatform/assets/xxx/64bit/8300123/libs/libxxx.so (deleted)
    #01 pc 0000000002cb038c  /data/data/com.sankuai.meituan/files/cips/common/mtplatform/assets/mtwebview/64bit/8300123/libs/libmtwebviewchromium.so (deleted)

    #32 pc 00000000000d83c4  /data/data/com.xxx/files/cips/common/mtplatform/assets/xxx/64bit/8300123/oat/arm64/base.vdex (deleted)
    #33 pc 00000000005a2b98  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+1432)
    #34 pc 0000000000131814  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+20)
    #35 pc 00000000000d8040  /data/data/com.sankuai.meituan/files/cips/common/mtplatform/assets/mtwebview/64bit/8300123/oat/arm64/base.vdex (deleted)
    #36 pc 00000000002b4088  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so
```

What does (deleted) mean?

...8300123/libs/libxxx.so (deleted)